# How to copy all content in Intellisense of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

You know, when we press Ctrl + Space after typing an object name, the Intellisense will display a list of all members and methods that belongs to that object.  So that we can insert elements directly into our code, and have IntelliSense complete our typing for us.

Is there any way to copy all such members and methods' names as text into notepad?

Comment: Well, you can always go to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) and do whatever you want with the documentation there.

Comment: @KenWhite, that's supposing the members he is interested in are from the .NET Framework, which may not be the case. Even if it was a .NET object, you still have extension methods and you don't have all the available members listed in one unique page.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to find an easy cut & paste way to do it.

But look into [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/).  It provides an API for doing just such a thing if you can make a visual studio extension.